# How to optimize the select attributes in Grails?

Tags: grails, query-optimization, grails-orm

I have an application in production use, when a user goes to a proposal index page it takes a very long time and sometimes times out. I've narrowed down the issue to be a SQL statement that is selecting all the Proposal objects. The problem is the Proposal object has many images (byte[]) stored in memory that aren't being used in the index page. These images are huge thus causing the problem.

What are the different ways I can optimize this query in Grails to remove the attributes I don't need on that page or only add the attributes I have in my GSP?

Here is the controller code (scaffolded):

```
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Proposal.list(params), model:[proposalInstanceCount: Proposal.count()]
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a plugin for this scenario, see http://grails.org/plugin/lazylob

Another option is to refactor the domain class into two. Put the image data in the new domain class:

```
class ProposalImage {
   byte[] image
}
```

and reference it from the Proposal class:

```
class Proposal {
   ProposalImage proposalImage
   // other properties
}
```

Since references are lazy by default, GORM will only load the image data from the new domain class if you specifically refer to it.

**EDIT (updated with subselect approaches):**

You can also use custom queries to select a subset of the properties. Probably the most convenient would be using "select new map" in an HQL query:

```
def results = Proposal.executeQuery(
   'select new map(prop1 as prop1, prop2 as prop2) from Proposal',
   [max:params.max as int, params.offset as int])
```

This is convenient because each element in the results list is a map keyed with the property names, so it will look the same as a real Proposal instance in the GSP.

Another option if you prefer criteria queries is to use projections to limit which properties are returned:

```
def results = Proposal.withCriteria {
   projections {
      property 'prop1'
      property 'prop2'
   }
   maxResults(params.max as int)
   firstResult(params.offset as int)
}
```

Each item in the results is an Object[] array and each element in the array is the actual type of the property. You would need to manually build a list of maps, e.g.

```
results = results.collect { result -> [prop1: result[0], prop2: result[1]] }
```

Additionally, you can automate this by finding all of the names of the persistent properties and excluding the one (or ones) you want to avoid: `def propNames = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(Proposal.name).persistentProperties*.name`

Comment: Thanks @burt, but both your ways change the model. Is there another way to do this without changing the model? (I'm not against changing the model, I just want to see all options) Maybe there should be an enhancement to have only the attributes listed in the GSP be in the selected attributes?

Comment: Thanks again @burt, I like the 3rd and 4th approaches but one thing that bugs me is that I have to be explicit about which properties I want in. If I change the GSP and forget to change the controller then this can cause issues. I wish there was an automatic way for grails to know this. I'm thinking I might be able to do it with reflection but it should probably be an option in list loading. Do you think its a good idea for an enhancement request?

Comment: I added some code that will let you find all of the persistent properties. That way you can be sure that if the class changes you'll still include everything the GSP expects.

Comment: @burt Great info about the domain class persistent property list. Many thanks.